Serilog with Elastic.Serilog.Sinks - minimum log level is not reflected
I am trying to implement logging in an ASP.NET Core 8 application with Serilog (version 8.0.1) and the "new" Elastic.Serilog.Sinks (version 8.11.1) library. I am stuck at setting minimum log level for the Elasticsearch sink.
Here is the problematic part of my simple sample application:
var builder = WebApplication
                 .CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
   .MinimumLevel.Debug()
   .WriteTo.Console()
   .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") }, opts =>
   {
      opts.MinimumLevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error;
      opts.BootstrapMethod = BootstrapMethod.Failure;
      opts.LevelSwitch = SwitchProvider.ElasticSwitch;
      opts.DataStream = new DataStreamName("logs", "web-api-example");
    })
);

As you can see I set the global minimumLevel to Debug and the Elasticsearch minimum level to Error. However all logs, no matter the level (well, all logs with higher level than the global minimumLevel to be precise), are sent to the Elasticsearch - I can see Debug, Information etc. level logs in Elasticsearch (basically the logs in console and in Elasticsearch are the same).
I have also tried to switch the level for Elasticsearch sink at runtime via the
ElasticSwitch.MinimumLevel = Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error;

through my basic SwitchProvider which is here:
public static class SwitchProvider
{
   public static LoggingLevelSwitch ElasticSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
}

but with no effect.
Am I missing something here?

You could try not using global configuration, but using sub loggers to configure console sink and elasticSearch sink.
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console())
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .MinimumLevel.Error()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new[] { new Uri("http://localhost:9200") }, opts =>
        {
            opts.BootstrapMethod = BootstrapMethod.Failure;
            opts.LevelSwitch = SwitchProvider.ElasticSwitch;
            opts.DataStream = new DataStreamName("logs", "web-api-example");
        })
));

